# How do I use the filedialog in electron?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I am new to electron and I am trying to open a filedialog that lets the user select a specific file using this code:

```
const {remote} = require("remote");
const {dialog} = require('electron').remote;

function openFileDialog() {
    const savePath = dialog.showSaveDialog();
    console.log(savePath)
}
```

However when I try this I get an error in the console saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showSaveDialog' of
> undefined.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**:
I am using this piece of code now as it was proposed below:

```
var remote = require("remote");
var dialog = require('dialog').remote; 

function openFileDialog() {
    const savePath = dialog.showSaveDialog(null);
    console.log(savePath)
}
```

inside a file named settings.js which I invoke using this code:

```
<input class="btn btn-dark" type="button" value="Input" onclick="openFileDialog();">
```

And I import the script using this code:

```
   <script src="./../javascript/settings.js"></script>
```

I have tried both with and without remote. I still get the same error

Comment: Where are you defining this function?

Comment: if u running this code in renderer process, first u have to import `remote`, only then `const { dialog } = remote;` https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it using these pieces of code. The first problem was that I needed to enable remoteModule `enableRemoteModule: true,` then that I needed to wait for the DOM to load using this code:

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("dialogBtn").addEventListener("click", openFileDialog);
}
```

Thank you Majed Badawi for the help!

Answer (score 3):

This should work if you're using it in the `main` process, if you want to use it from a `renderer` process:

```
const { dialog } = require('electron').remote;
```

Also, it's better to define the `event-handler` in the script. Here is a functional example:

```
<input class="btn btn-dark" type="button" value="Input" id="dialogBtn">
```

```
const { dialog } = require('electron').remote;

document.getElementById("dialogBtn").addEventListener("click", openFileDialog);

async function openFileDialog() {
  try {
    const savePath = await dialog.showSaveDialog(null);
    console.log('savePath: ', savePath);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error:', e);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question. What does it mean by using it from a render process?

Comment: @VictorGunnarsson the ``main`` process is the file ``main.js`` where the ``BrowserWindow`` is created for example. While a ``renderer`` process is the one that you use in the scripts of the UI for example which seems your case. However, I notice that you're importing ``dialog`` the wrong way, try to use the above solution.

Comment: I ran the above solution locally and opened the dialog normally

Comment: Thank you for you help and patience, I just pasted in your code. However I now get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'dialog' of 'require(...).remote' as it is undefined.